# Datetime function: semester, quarter

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime

I am using these formulas on a select query, based on the [Date] field. Semester is 1 for Jan-Jun, 2 for Jul-Dec. Quarter is the 3-month version (1 for Jan-Mar etc).

```
case when Month([Date])>=7 then 2 else 1 end as [Semester],
ceiling((Month([Date])-1)/3)+1 as [Quarter]
```

These work, but I am wondering if there is a simpler/more elegant solution (although I've checked the datetime functions out).

It seems strange to me that a language with an ntile() function would not have something similar for dates.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[DATEPART](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datepart-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) is suitable for your case.

```
CASE WHEN DATEPART(quarter,[Date]) >= 3 THEN 2 ELSE 1 END as [Semester],
DATEPART(quarter,[Date]) as [Quarter]
```

Answer (score 3):

[`DATEPART`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datepart-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) can easily give you quarter.

It doesn't have an option for semester or half-year, but you can easily derive that from quarter using similar maths to that you're currently using for your quarter calculation.

```
((DATEPART(quarter,[Date])-1)/2)+1 as [Semester],
DATEPART(quarter,[Date]) as [Quarter]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
    CASE WHEN month([DATE]) < 7 then  '01'
    else '02'
    end
FROM [Table]
```

You can get the semester number from MONTH(date)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe later.
For semester : `cast(ceiling((extract(MONTH FROM madate))/6) as integer)`